# eclipse launcher icon in kde

Tags: 14.04, kubuntu, launcher, icons

I installed 14.04 with Unity on my new box. Works pretty good. I installed Eclipse under Unity, but still haven't been able to create a launcher that displays the Eclipse icon. For other reasons I installed `kubuntu-desktop` and would now like to create a desktop launcher for the already installed Eclipse.

Initially I did a search in `kickstart` and drug the icon onto the desktop. This launches Eclipse with no trouble, but it has only the default gear icon.

So then I went to Dolphin and browsed to `/usr/share/applications` and drug out the .deskktop file I created there for Unity onto the KDE desktop. Now I have a desktop icon that has the proper Eclipse icon. But when I click it, Eclipse doesn't launch.

How can I get one icon on the KDE desktop with the proper Eclipse Luna icon (which is `/usr/share/icons/eclipse.png` -- I converted the icon.xpm file and put it there) that actually launches Eclipse?

**Update --**

Two things were needed. I had the permissions wrong on the `.png` file. It needed to be readable by everyone. Then the `.desktop` file needed to look like this:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Comment[en_US]=
Comment=
Exec=/home/tarka/eclipse/eclipse
GenericName[en_US]=
GenericName=
Icon=eclipse
MimeType=
Name[en_US]=eclipse
Name=eclipse
Path=
StartupNotify=true
Terminal=false
TerminalOptions=
Type=Application
X-DBUS-ServiceName=
X-DBUS-StartupType=
X-KDE-SubstituteUID=false
X-KDE-Username=
```

The key piece as in the comment was the line `Icon=eclipse`. Still don't know why it wouldn't work with the full path.

Comment: Added an answer, check it and if it works click the grey ☑ under the "0" at the left of this text, which means "I accept the answer" and also upvote!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the shortcut with some text editor like *gedit* or *kate* icon by right-clicking on it, and selecting "Open with gedit". In the text editor, shortly after the 'comment' and 'app command' text, you should see something like 'Icon=exec,' (ignore the quotes) change it to `Icon=/usr/share/icons/eclipse.png` or `Icon=eclipse`

Comment: Thanks for the answer and congratulations: you fixed the Unity icon. I found the permissions for the .png file were for root only. Now Unity displays the icon normally. But the question was for KDE desktop. There is no `edit` option when right clicking in KDE, but I found the path to the .desktop file and changed the icon location. Now KDE shows no icon at all. It's just blank.

Comment: Right click on the shortcut (.desktop) file and edit it with kate or gedit then add following line to it Icon=/usr/share/icons/eclipse.png , if it doesnt work , write Icon=eclipse